# ng-view doesnt display the view

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to load a login.hml to my index.html using angular-route and ng-view, but for some reason it doesnt work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Test">
  <head>
      <script src="public/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="public/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script src="public/lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="public/modules/core/core.client.module.js"></script>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="cf" ng-include="'public/modules/navigation/views/nav.html'"></nav>
    </header>
    <div class="page">
      <main class="cf" ng-view></main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A very simple JS file which loads the Angular modlule and call the $routeProvider for `/login` url:

```
var myApp = angular.module('Test',['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
        }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/about'});
}]);
```

login.html:

```
<h1>
    <p>Login</p>
</h1>
```

Comment: fix filename to templateUrl: 'views/login.html'

Comment: Apologies, that was in my initial code it still didnt work. I will edit my code

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I think the problem is with the path to file you use, what is the file mentioned in the 404?

Comment: yes its looking for views/login.html in my base directory, however my project structure is Base->public->modules->core->views->login.html also my core.client.module.js is in that directory too,  my index.html is in the base directory , i cant post image as i have < 10 reputation

Comment: It works once i pass entire path from base, thanks